# value of a variable in a div id html/xsl

Tags: html, xslt

```
 <div id="$var"> </div>
```

$var is the value of a variable var. For example var="apple". This is also in a loop so the value of var is changing.
When i run the program i want to have `<div id="apple">` and then `<div id="pear">` etc.

Is it possible to do so? if yes, how?

Comment: Pleas post a reproducible example, including the XML input, your current XSLT and the expected output - see:[mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** `{}` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template

```
...<div id="{$var}">...
```

**II.** `<xsl:attribute>` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes

```
...
<xsl:element name="div">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
       <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
   </attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

> The xsl:attribute element can be used to add attributes to result elements whether created by literal result elements in the stylesheet or by instructions such as xsl:element.

Comment: After two months of research, finally got this, Dspace gave me a lot of trouble thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add brackets

```
<div id="{$var}"> </div>
```